# Google Tag Manager Custom Template Sandboxed Javascript Problem

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have created a custom template using  google tag manager,  however I am having some difficulty in getting my sandboxed javascript to work,  I know that the script is injected correctly becuase the following

> log('Cotaylitcs: Script loaded successfully.');

outputs to the console.  I'm just not able to call my functions.  I have included the JS code as well.

**Custom Template Code (Sandboxed Javascript)**

```
// Enter your template code here.
const log = require('logToConsole');
const injectScript = require('injectScript');
const copyFromWindow = require('copyFromWindow');
const callInWindow = require('callInWindow');
const callLater = require('callLater');
const setInWindow = require('setInWindow');

const key = "testing";
const value = "test2";
const url = 'https://api.deve/cotalytics/cotalytics.js';


// If the script loaded successfully, log a message and signal success
const onSuccess = () => {
  log('Cotaylitcs: Script loaded successfully.');


  const cotalytics = copyFromWindow('cotalytics');
  log(cotalytics);
  callInWindow('cotalytics.addEvent',"testing12" ,{key: value}, "{{DL - cottageCode}}");
  callInWindow('cotalytics.logEvents()');
  data.gtmOnSuccess();
};

// If the script fails to load, log a message and signal failure
const onFailure = () => {
  log('Cotaylitcs: Script load failed.');
  data.gtmOnFailure();
};

injectScript(url, onSuccess, onFailure, 'cotalytics');
```

**My Javascript code that is injected by Sandboxed Js:**

```
let Cotalytics = function(){
    this.init();
};

// Init
Cotalytics.prototype = 
{
    init: function () {

        var cotalytics = this;

        // Argument Assignment                                                                              
        //cotalytics.endpoint           =  'https://localhost:44301/api/events/',
        //cotalytics.async              =  true,
        //cotalytics.debug              = true,
        //cotalytics.events             = {}

        //creat cookie here

        return cotalytics;
    },
      // Add Interaction Object Triggered By Events to Records Array
    addEvent: function (eventType, data, cottageCode, brandid) {
        data = data || {};
        cottageCode = cottageCode || null;

        data.Browser = window.navigator.appVersion;

        var cotalytics  = this;

            // cotalytics Object
            cotalytics.events     = {
                timestamp       : new Date(),
                cottagecode     : cottageCode,
                type            : eventType,
                ipaddress       : "127.0.0.1",
                requesturl      : window.location.href,
                sessionid       : "1234567",
                brandid         : brandid,
                eventData  : Object.keys(data).map(function(key) { return {"key": key, "value": data[key]}})
            };


        // Log Interaction if Debugging

            //cotalytics.logEvents();
            //console.log("Session:\n", interactor.interaction);
            //var data =JSON.stringify(interactor)
           console.log("JSON:\n", JSON.stringify(cotalytics));


        return cotalytics;
    },
     // Gather Additional Data and Send Interaction(s) to Server
     logEvents: function () {

        var cotalytics  = this,
            // Initialize Cross Header Request
            xhr         = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Post Session Data Serialized as JSON
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://localhost:44301/api/events/', true);

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        var data = JSON.stringify(cotalytics.events);
        xhr.send(data);

        return cotalytics;
        }
};


window.cotalytics = new Cotalytics();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like you're mostly there, but there are a few things that aren't quite right.

1. The use of `{key: value}` in the addEvent call. Whilst the value will be populated with your constant, the key won't be. I'm imagining that these will be dynamic variables, so why don't you have something like:

```
const kvp= {};
const key = "yourKey";
const value = "yourValue";
kvp[key] = value;
```

That will create the object with the key you want and not just "key".

2. This line here won't work. you can't use container variables in a custom template.

`callInWindow('cotalytics.addEvent',"testing12" ,{key: value}, "{{DL - cottageCode}}");`

It looks like a dataLayer variable, so why don't you use the copyFromDataLayer API and try this?

```
const copyFromDataLayer = require('copyFromDataLayer');
const cottageCode = copyFromDataLayer('cottageCode');
```

3. The logEvents callInWindow `callInWindow('cotalytics.logEvents()');` doesn't need the brackets, it's just `callInWindow('cotalytics.logEvents');`.

The final code that I got working was:

```
const log = require('logToConsole');
const injectScript = require('injectScript');
const callInWindow = require('callInWindow');
const makeTableMap = require('makeTableMap');
const copyFromDataLayer = require('copyFromDataLayer');

const cottageCode = copyFromDataLayer('cottageCode');

//Create the Key Value Pair
const kvp = {};
const key = "testing";
const value = "test2";
kvp[key]=value;

const url = "https://api.deve/cotalytics/cotalytics.js";

// If the script loaded successfully, log a message and signal success
const onSuccess = () => {
  log('Cotaylitcs: Script loaded successfully.');
  callInWindow('cotalytics.addEvent',"testing12" ,kvp,cottageCode);
  callInWindow('cotalytics.logEvents');
  data.gtmOnSuccess();
};

// If the script fails to load, log a message and signal failure
const onFailure = () => {
  log('Cotaylitcs: Script load failed.');
  data.gtmOnFailure();
};

injectScript(url, onSuccess, onFailure, 'cotalytics');
```

Hopefully that helps, ask if you have any other questions!

Comment: Thanks James,  it worked for a bit but now I am getting Still Running status on the fired tag

Comment: I'm guessing that this is as the tag and not in the template builder? Still Running generally means that the onSuccess/Failure events haven't fired yet, so it's possible that the tag is hanging somewhere. Check the network tab when the tag fires and see what calls are being made and also put some console logs back in to see where the code gets to. Alternatively if you share the site link and container preview I'm happy to have a look at it.

Comment: When I looked at the site the js file you're loading has these lines.
 xhr.open('POST', 'https://localhost:44301/api/events/', true);
        //xhr.open('POST', 'https://cotalytics-test.azurewebsites.net/api/events/', true);
That's potentially causing problems, and would definitely stop me from testing, however I can't see the events firing. Can you put in a console log in the on success for all the variables you're calling?

Comment: Sandboxed JS - `// If the script loaded successfully, log a message and signal success
const onSuccess = () => {
  log('Cotaylitcs: Script loaded successfully.');
  log('Cotaylitcs: KVP');
   log(kvp);
  log('Cotaylitcs: cottagecode');
  log(cottageCode);
    log('Cotaylitcs: apikey');
  log(apikey);
 
  callInWindow('cotalytics.addEvent',"testing12" ,kvp, cottageCode);
  log('Cotaylitcs: Passed ad event ');
  callInWindow('cotalytics.logEvents', apikey);
  log('Cotaylitcs: Passed log event ');
  data.gtmOnSuccess();
};`

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this now.  I am still using the Custom template but I needed to add a new custom HTML tag that injected my .JS script into all pages after doing this my custom template tag worked.